# Monitor goes black on onHover events after waking from hibernate

Tags: windows-10, display, sleep, lenovo-laptop

I'm experiencing a very weird phenomenon:
After waking from hibernate, built-in laptop screen goes black whenever the mouse cursor hovers over a visual element on the screen. It only happens on the internal monitor, regardless of whether an external monitor is attached or not.
The only thing that resolves the issue is restarting the OS.

What has been tried without an effect:
Uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers (graphics and chipset).
Restarting Windows services.
Restarting display drivers (Ctrl+Win+Shift+B)

OS: Windows 10 Pro 20H2
iGPU - Intel Iris Plus (i7-1065G7).
Laptop: Lenovo Yoga C940-14

Comment: Run Lenovo System Update and update all drivers including BIOS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Already did, same result.

Comment: Try running a Windows 10 Repair Install from the Media Creation Link:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10